# To manage tool buttons with the toolbar off

Tags: intellij-idea

When toolbar is switched off (menu: View->Toolbar) there are still some buttons on "toolbar".

[image]

How I can add (remove) tools/commands to this area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize any menu or toolbar in IDEA in settings by going to:

> Settings-> Appearance and Behavior -> Menus and Toolbars

[image]

---

The item you are looking for is called

> Navigation Bar Toolbar

[image]

---

More info here

```
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/menus-and-toolbars-2.html
```

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the [Navigation Bar Toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnQya.png).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have IntelliJ Idea, but I think in PyCharm it work the same - when your toolbar is switched on, you can right click on it and customize all panels in Idea. So you can do it, and then switch off toolbar again.

[PyCharm Customize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nueuZ.png)